# Whitelist implementation of Ownable.sol

Tags: factory, clone

I'm creating a Whitelist dapp.
I want users to have the ability to submit a form onClick/submit which will store a new list and deploy a contract that they own.

I've come to the conclusion that a factory pattern would be best to deploy clones of the contract cheaply.
I'm looking into Ownable.sol but find it a little confusing.

- Should the main contract AND the factory contract be Ownable?
- Which contract would the user deploy?
- Is it best that I write the contract so I am owner of both contracts and then put a transferOwnership function inside the cloneContract Function?
  This means I would pay gas fees for every user that deploys a contract right?

I've entered a hackathon and am pretty new to web3 dev. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you can implement ownable in the "Factory contract" in the case you want to add owner only functions like "pause clones", etc.  You could also implement ownable in the "Contract to be cloned" (Base Contract) so you can also add special owner only functions that should only be accessed by the owner of the contract

What I would do is a "factory contract" with a external/public function that any end user can call..

I'd call this function `newContract(parameters)` and its purpose would be to deploy a clone of an implementation contract

Since the end user is the one calling the contract, he will be the owner of the deployed contract; Ownable calls  `_transferOwnership(_msgSender())` in its constructor